# Using AsyncTask to read items from a database

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I decided to add an `AsyncTask` to a fragment in my app in order to receive items from the database more efficiently.

I set my generics to `Void, Void, List<Object>` (where `Object` is an object I created), 
and the inner methods as follows:

```
private class GetObjectsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Object>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Object> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                .........
        };

        String sortOrder = ...;

        Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, sortOrder);

        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            long itemId = ...;
            String title = ...;
            long startMil = ...;
            long endMil = ...;

            mList.add(new Object(itemId, title, new Date(startMil), new Date(endMil), null, null));
        }

        db.close();
        return mList;
    }
}
```

and here is how I call the task from the same fragment:
`new GetObjectsTask().execute((Void[]) null);`

After the execution of the task, I set a list view to show items from the array.
The exact same code was used before without a task so it should work.
The problem is - it doesn't.
`mList` is defined in the fragment that is holding this inner task class, so I expected it to work.

**What could cause such behavior?

Also, would it be possible (and recommanded) to make the task set the list view to show the returned items as well? (by overriding `onPostExecute(Result)`)**

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

onPostExecute(Result) is exactly the place where you should initialize your listview and set adapter. Cause onPostExecute() is running in main UI thread.

Comment: You're not dojng anything with the data in your example. Return the list and it will be passed to onPostExecute where you can use it for any UI function. You cannot access the UI from a background thread.